# Assignment problem with multiple persons needed on each job

Tags: algorithm

First, sorry if my English isn't so good, I'm not a native English speaker.

I'm facing an assignment problem.

I have a list of jobs, with a certain number of persons needed for each job. Each person will let me know on how many jobs they want to be and their preferences.

I tried to do that with the Hungarian Algorithm but it seems I'm unable to get it done. With a large number of jobs and spots, some persons got multiple time the same job, which isn't ok.
I think it's all due to the fact I considered each spot as an individual job and I listed each person as many times as they need to be placed.

Do you know a better algorithm or a way to do it?

(It's not a coding problem, I'm doing it in Octave/Matlab for now, but I think I'll switch to Python.)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Henrik's suggestion to use Linear Programming, your specific problem can also be solved using [Minimum cost maximum flow](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.854/06/scribe/s12-minCostFlowAlg.pdf).

You make a bipartite graph between people and jobs (like in the Hungarian algorithm), where the cost on the middle edges are the preference scores, and the capacity is 1.
The capacity of the edges from the jobs to the sink is the number of people you need for that job.

Comment: It's perhaps worth spelling out that the graph is not quite bipartite as the sink belongs to neither partition. Moreover, the OP has specified that a person can take multiple jobs (which you'd then include by also adding a source with edges to each person, weighted by the number of jobs that person wants).

Answer (score 0):

Assignment problems can be solved with linear programming:

Let xij = 1 if person i is assigned to job j and 0 otherwise. Let aij be the rank for person i of job j : aij = 1 for the job he wants most, aij = 2 for the next and so on. If he only wants k jobs you put aij to a very high number for all jobs beyond those k.

If you need at least bj workers on job j you have the constraint

x1j + ... + xmj >= bj   (j = 1,...,n)

You also have the constraints xij >= 0 and xij <= 1 .

The linear function to minimize is

sum( aij xij ) over all i,j

Comment: Hey @Henrik4, thanks for this answer. I think I've done something quite close to that, but where I'm stuck is how to solve it.
With only one job per worker, Hungarian algorithm is working well.
Can I adapt this algorithm or find something else similar?

Comment: @Raghnarok For LP problems there is a standard solution algorithm: The simplex method. How to adapt the hungarian algo I don't know; ask the chap above.